# how to find which query or mutation is taking how much time in graphql project?

Tags: node.js, graphql

Suppose we have written the graphql query in the following way

```
type Query {
    user: User
    book: Book
}
```

My question is how much time **user** takes to written user details and
how much time **book** takes to written book details.

Just want to find time taken by each query to complete.

Comment: You can always use a simple NodeJS profiler. Or classic debugging method of printing the time taken by each resolver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apollo graphql server then we can just configure tracing and check the time taken by request in graphql playground.
Just need to updated the config with  tracing: true